# How can I move the cursor left or right inside a line?

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code that moves the cursor line by line. Now at a specific line I want to move left or right. How can I do that?  I tried `seekg(int num , ios::cur)` and it just went down another line.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num) {
    string item;
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
   for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');   
    }
   file.seekg(3, ios::cur); ///so i will be able to print blabla in line 9 at bla.txt
    return file;
}

int main() {

    fstream file("bla.txt");

    GotoLine(file, 8);

    string line8;
    file >> line8;

    cout << line8;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

bla.txt

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9. blabla
10.
```

Comment: "*I tried `seekg(int num , ios::cur)` and it just went down another line*" - please show the actual code you tried.

Comment: Line 8 has characters `8.` in it and no `blabla`. That would be line 9. If you think you have line 0, think again.